# Ruby/Minitest Spec: How to test that a method returns a value within a given array?

Tags: ruby, minitest

I have the following class:

```rb
  class State
    def self.alive
      :alive
    end

    def self.dead
      :dead
    end
  end
```

Testing is simple:

```
it 'should report the expected state for alive' do
  State.alive.must_equal :alive
end

it 'should report the expected state for dead' do
  State.dead.must_equal :dead
end
```

I want to add a class method which returns a random state.

```rb
class State
# ...
    def self.random
      [alive, dead].sample
    end
```

However, I'm unsure of which assertion I need to use.

Currently, I am testing it as follows:

```rb
  it 'should return a random state' do
    %i[dead alive].must_include State.random
  end
```

Which is back to front. The test above is testing the literal array rather that the `State` class.

Is there a better way to test that a method returns a value included within a specified array?

Comment: You are testing the ruby core. `Array#sample` works, take it for granted. Also, there is no “back to forth” in your test, if you still want to test ruby, your test is fine.

Answer (score 3):

Before I offer you a solution, I want to unravel some details about the Spec DSL and Minitest. The `must_include` methods is the Spec DSL expectation for the `assert_includes` assertion. That method has the following signature:

```rb
assert_includes collection, obj, msg = nil
```

When the expectation is created, the signature is:

```rb
Collection#must_include obj, msg = nil
```

So what you are really asking is for a way of calling these methods with the argument order reversed. This is pretty simple to do by creating new methods that use your desired argument order. First, we must create the assertion:

```rb
module Minitest::Assertions
  ##
  # Fails unless +obj+ is included in +collection+.

  def assert_included_in obj, collection, msg = nil
    msg = message(msg) {
      "Expected #{mu_pp(obj)} to be included in #{mu_pp(collection)}"
    }
    assert_respond_to collection, :include?
    assert collection.include?(obj), msg
  end
end
```

Now that we have the assertion method, we can create the Spec DSL expectation:

```rb
module Minitest::Expectations
  ##
  # See Minitest::Assertions#assert_included_in
  #
  #    collection.must_be_one_of obj
  #
  # :method: must_be_one_of

  infect_an_assertion :assert_included_in, :must_be_one_of, :reverse
end
```

Now that we have defined the expectation, and the assertion it uses, we can use it in the test:

```rb
it "should return a random state" do
  State.random.must_be_one_of %i[dead alive]
end
```

I would take it one step further, and use the value monad to call the expectation:

```rb
it "should return a random state" do
  value(State.random).must_be_one_of %i[dead alive]
end
```